# How to patch holes in freezer wall?

Tags: hole-repair, freezer

I have a chest freezer with several holes in its metal lining, as pictured below. Can I just slap some HVAC tape over these, or is there a better material or approach? Do I need to worry about filling in the insulation, and if so how?

Larger holes in freezer wall:
[image]

Smaller holes in freezer floor:
[image]

Whole freezer, for scale:
[image]

Comment: I think HVAC tape (rated for say -25F) would work.   If not, and it comes off, it's going to look like hell anyway.  It seems the ice pick used was pretty dull!

Comment: you probably want to fill or insulate the void behind the path to keep air out; otherwise it can condense can cause mildew inside the unit, or in extreme cases, drip and damage the floor. Even a wadded up plastic bag would work; just something non-porous to fill the space so that air cannot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

refrigerated truck compartments are basically made of the same stuff as your freezer body.

So there's a method designed for reparing foam filled aluminium panels.

It seems to be squirt-foam to fill the void, and then after the foam has set, a two part adhesive to glue an aluminium patch over the hole.

product reccomendations are off topic, but a search on "repair foam filled aluminium panel" gets plenty of results.

Answer (score 0):

You might cut some pieces of Aluminum sheet to fit and affix with silicone adhesive.